# How to eject Windows 7 DVD when installing on MacBook Pro?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, macbook-pro, eject

During the installation process of Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro, it asks me to eject the DVD so that I can put in a disk with drivers.  I have the driver disk but I can't figure out how to eject the DVD.  Pressing a holding the eject button doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Write the .iso at 2x not 8x, so that the MacBook can read it and doesn't need you to insert another disk.